# Error in MySQL Syntax; Problems Creating a Table and decimal(19,4) & bigint Datatypes

Tags: mysql

First of all, I'm very new to MySQL.  I'm trying to create a table to store (historical) financial pricing data as part of an algorithmic trading system I'm developing.

So far, I have created 3 other tables with ease.  However, for this 4th table (daily_price), I have come up against issues.  These issues I feel, seem to arise around the use of the decimal(19,4) and bigint data types.

My code is found below.  I've had a look around online and books etc, but my problem seems quite unique.  Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! Matt

```
CREATE TABLE daily_price 
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
data_vendor_id INT NOT NULL, 
symbol_id INT NOT NULL, 
price_date datetime NOT NULL, 
created_date datetime NOT NULL,
last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
open_price decimal(19,2) NULL, 
high_price decimal(19,4) NULL, 
adj_close_price decimal(19,4) NULL, 
volume bigint NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), 
KEY index_data_vendor (data_vendor_id), 
KEY index_symbol_id (symbol_id)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I'd recommend typing the SQL statement line by line in MySQL. Just hit enter whenever you want and continue. As long as you finish at the very end of the last statement with a semicolon the code will run. This will tell you what line there is an error on. Also, look into using HeidiSQL. It lets you interact with your database in a GUI application. Much easier for database management and debugging

Comment: Could you edit the code you are trying to run into the question? it would be much easier to read that way.

Comment: @ander2ed I just edited it

Comment: Thank you @Michael, that certainly helps. However, based on the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/454Vf.png it looks like you are missing at least one column (last_updated_date). Further, I suspect OP is dealing with a specific syntax issue, so seeing the exact code OP is trying to run (opposed to code translated from an image by someone else) may provide more insight.

Comment: @ander2ed good catch. I fixed it now, I was actually missing a couple. Also is the code he posted not what he is trying to run? If not OP definitely should post the code

Comment: Well, based on the image, OP ran the code and it failed. So presumably that is the code he is trying to run. My only point was that by translating the code from the image there is a real possibility to make a mistake, or possibly fixing any syntax errors OP may have had. For example, the MySQL error message in the image shows `open_price decimal(19,4)NULL`, without a space between `(19,4)` and `NULL`. Your code doesn't reflect that. Again, I really do appreciate you took the time to edit that in, I just wonder if that is the *exact* code OP was running.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys!  I'm going to have good hard think again about this.  I took your advice Michael by typing the code line by line.  The issues are related to: data_vendor INT NOT NULL, symbol_id INT NOT NULL and price_date datetime NOT NULL; again, syntax issues.